# Listening to gestures on an App widget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I have created an app widget in Android and want to add some gesture-based functionality to it. For e.g: when user swipes up new set of data be displayed.
AFAIK, gestures are not supported in AppWidgets and yet I have seen widgets which have similar functionality(e.g. HTC widgets photo album and weather widget).

Please help me out and let men know if I am missing something.

Link to tutorials, documentation or sample code are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot respond to gestures in app widgets, sorry. The only interactions presently supported are simple click events.

Comment: Hi Mark! Thanks for your reply. Any guesses on how HTC photo album widget and weather widget handle gestures?

Comment: @Samuh: Simple. They're not app widgets. They are part of the home screen application, merely advertised as and configured like app widgets.

Comment: Games that people play! :)
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

There is one case where this happens, the ics unlock screen widget. I hear you, it's not really a homescreen widget, but it is equivalent in the case of widgetlocker. If you could hack that functionality you might have what you need.

I've been thinking about a heavily customized version of this for a while.